# Not able to display highcharts in php

Tags: php, highcharts

i have just started to use HighCharts in one of my implementation but i wasn't able to render the charts with the following codes. Does i miss out anything?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" height="100%">

<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">     
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chart;
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Testing'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right'
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 60,
                x: -60
            },
            tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                    return this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                data: []
            }]
        }

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The output of my data file is something like this:

`[["A",13],["B",3],["C",7]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot a comma in your code, Change:

```
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
align: 'right'
verticalAlign: 'top',
```

to:

```
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
```

Here is a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/HCJCr/

Tip: Learn how to use the debugger in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox. You will spot these errors and others in a second. It's worth the time.